# How set postion and size image variables Stimulsoft Core?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, stimulsoft

I am using stimulsoft for ASP.NET Core MVC.
I want to get image variables and set setting properties for image.
This my code:

```
public ActionResult GetReportSnapshot(string sort)
{
        StiReport report = new StiReport();
        report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Jobs.mrt"));

        report["@PrjectId"] = 1;
        report["@OrderBy"] = sort;
      
        // this is the problem:
        report.Dictionary.Variables["image"].width=5
    
        report.Render();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem like this:

```
  StiReport report = new StiReport();
  var image = report.GetComponentByName("Image1") as StiImage;
  image.CanGrow =false ;
```